# JQuery - how to add an OnChange handler to Textbox in an IFrame

Tags: jquery, telerik

I have an ASP page using a Telerik TabStrip. The contents of one of the tabs is an iFrame , with the source just a basic HTML page with a textbox.

The page looks like this:

```
 <telerik:RadTabStrip RenderMode="Lightweight" runat="server" ID="RadTabStrip1"  MultiPageID="RadMultiPage1" SelectedIndex="0" Skin="MetroTouch">
            <Tabs>
                <telerik:RadTab Text="AppX" Width="400px"></telerik:RadTab>
                <telerik:RadTab Text="Cognitive Search" Width="200px"></telerik:RadTab>
                <telerik:RadTab Text="About" Width="200px"></telerik:RadTab>
            </Tabs>
        </telerik:RadTabStrip>
        <telerik:RadMultiPage runat="server" ID="RadMultiPage1" Height="100%" 
          Width="100%"  SelectedIndex="0" CssClass="outerMultiPage">

            <telerik:RadPageView runat="server" ID="RadPageAppX" Height="90%" 
           Width="100%">

                  **<iframe src="AppX.html"**  style="position: absolute; height: 
            90%; border: none" runat="server" id="IFrameAppX" name="IFrameAppX"  
            />

            </telerik:RadPageView>
```

The HTML page in the tab is AppX.html and looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <input id="SearchTerm" type="text"  value="SEARCH-TERM" 

</body>
</html>
```

When the page loads I need to add an OnChange handler , to the SearchTerm in the page, that's in the iFrame.  I have tried the following but nothing works.

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
         $("#MainContent_IFrameAppX#SearchTerm").bind("change", function () 
   {
              console.log("OnChange");
           });


  $("#IFrameAppX").contents().find('SearchTerm').bind("change", function () 
   {

                var frame = document.getElementById("IFrameAppX");
                var txt = 
     frame.contentWindow.$(SearchTerm).val("hello").change();

            });




 $("#MainContent_IFrameAppX").contents().find('SearchTerm').bind("change", 
 function () {
                    console.log("OnChange");
                });
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?   thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

i think you left a # out before SearchTerm

```
$("#IFrameAppX").contents().find('#SearchTerm').on("change", function () 
{
   //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have to wait for iFrame to load before I can attach handler!

```
        $("#IFrameAppX").ready(function () {                        
              $("#MainContent_IFrameAppX").contents().find("#SearchTerm").bind("change", function () {
                        console.log($("#MainContent_IFrameAppX").contents().find("#SearchTerm").val());
                        alert("Change");
                    });
                  });
```